# MultiValueDictKeyError at /app/index "'access_key'"

Tags: python, django

I got an error `MultiValueDictKeyError` at **/app/index** `'access_key'` . I wrote in views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UserIDForm
from .models import User
import json
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound

def index(request):
    inp_id = request.POST['access_key']
    find = False

    if inp_id == 100:
       find = True

    if find:
        id_json = {"id": 100}
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()

    return JsonResponse(id_json, safe=False)
```

Now I use `POSTMAN`, and my ideal system is when I post Key is access_key& Value is 100 to `http://localhost:8000/app/index` in POSTMAN, {"id": 100} is returned. What is　matter in my code? Is it unicode error? How should I fix this?

[POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fixt3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inp_id = request.POST.get('access_key', None)
```

and you don't set `access_key` in your post request with POSTMAN,[this](http://oasis-story.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/media%2Ffile%2F20171101-165702-710.png) is the right way.

Comment: thx ur answer.I tried ur code,but I got TypeError at /app/index
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' error.I updated POSTMAN photo to my question,how should I fix this?

Comment: @user8817674 you haven't specified key as "access_key" in the post request with postman

Comment: see [POSTMAN](http://oasis-story.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/media%2Ffile%2F20171101-165702-710.png)